# Intercalar uma lista encadeada em c

Tags: c

Olá estou tentando fazer um exercicio onde preciso intercalar 2 listas encadeadas. Mas a minha função só esta retornando um numero apenas. A função é a intercala();

```
insira o código aqui
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LISTA{
    int dado;
    struct LISTA *prox;
} lista;

typedef struct LISTA2{
    int dado;
    struct LISTA2 *prox;
} lista2;

lista *insere(lista *p, int valor){ 
    lista *novo;
    novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->dado = valor;
    novo->prox = p;
    return novo;        
}

void imprime(lista *l){
    lista *p = l;
    for(p = l; p != NULL; p=p->prox){
        printf("%d-",p->dado);
    }
}

lista* intercala (lista* l, lista2* l2){    
    lista *li = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    lista *p1;
    lista2 *p2;

    for(p1 =l, p2 =l2; p1!= NULL && p2!=NULL; p1 =p1->prox, p2=p2->prox){
        li->dado = p1->dado;
        li->prox = p1->prox;
        li->dado = p2->dado;
        li->prox = p2->prox;
    }
    return li;
}

main(){     
    lista *l;
    lista2 *l2;
    l  = NULL;
    l2 = NULL;

    l = insere(l, 1);
    l = insere(l, 2);
    l = insere(l, 3);
    imprime(l);
    printf("\n");
    l2 = insere(l2, 4);
    l2 = insere(l2, 5);
    l2 = insere(l2, 6);
    imprime(l2);
    printf("\n");
    //concatena(l,l2);
    //imprime(l);
    l =intercala (l,l2);
    imprime(l);
}
```

Comment: Para intercalar é preciso alocar memoria na nova `lista` o tamanho de l1 + l2

Comment: Algo parecido com isso ?  lista *li = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista)+ sizeof(lista2))

Comment: Na estrutura das listas deveria de ter o tamanho de cada lista, depois fazia `tamanho * sizeof(lista)`

Comment: eu fiz 2 variveis globais pra pegar o tamanho e depois somei elas dentro do escopo mas mesmo assim nao funcionou. Acho que é a função que esta errada

Comment: Já comentei outra pergunta sua e volto a repetir, a sua implementação está fraca, eu avisei que mais tarde para usar em outras funções ia dar problema, sugeri ver a `lista` que implementei no GitHub

Comment: Essa implementação foi a que me foi ensinada na faculdade, esse semestre então vai ser meio difícil eu conseguir assimilar de forma diferente pois ainda estou aprendendo listas encadeadas talvez pra frente eu consiga resolver melhor.